# Why do custom claims appear in original identity object after I add them to a copy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project I am adding some custom claims to the `ClaimsIdentity` object after a user logs in.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
      options.Events.OnTicketReceived = context =>
      {   
          var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
          // custom claims
          AddCustomClaims(claimsIdentity);

          return;
      };
   ...
}

private void AddCustomClaims(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
{
    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("test1", "helloearth!!!"));
    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("test2", "helloplanet!!!"));
    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("test3", "helloworld!!!"));
}
```

If I set a breakpoint on the `return;` and take a look at the `context.Principal.Identity` object, all three claims appear there.

I don't understand why? I thought I made a copy of `context.Principal.Identity` and `AddCustomClaims` method only manipulated that copy. But somehow the original object is affected.

Comment: Where exactly did you make a copy of it? Perhaps you were thinking that `var claimsIdentity = ...` made a copy of it? If the object in `.Identity` is a class, aka a reference type, all you made a copy of was the reference, not the actual object it references. Is that it?

Comment: You can compare it to a house, that object. The thing you made a copy of was a post-it note with the address of the house on it. Now you have two post-it notes, but you still have only one house. Visiting the house and adding some furniture changes that single house.

Comment: Ok I see. I didn't realize `claimsIdentity` became another reference to the object. But now I tried it with a `string` type but the string is unaffected. Doesn't the string variable also point to the value of it?

Comment: Strings are immutable, but doing `variableName = newValue` changes the reference, but not the original object. If you do `variableName.Change` then you change the object. But yes, strings are immutable, you can't change them. But then no code you write would attempt to change it either.

Comment: Read some more about it and I understand it now. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the age-old confusion between variables and reference types.

To put it simply, you have two major categories of types in .NET, value types and reference types. When you introduce variables into the mix, variables holding value types hold the entire value, like a number, whereas variables holding reference types only hold a reference to an object, and that object is somewhere else in the memory of the computer.

Your `.Identity` property there contains such a reference, to an instance of a reference type, and thus when you did

```
var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
```

you didn't actually make another copy of the object, instead, you made a copy of the reference to it. I like to explain this using houses. Your object instance is a house, somewhere, and the variable is like a post-it note with the address to that house.

Your statement didn't build another house, it just made another post-it note with the same address on it.

Or in .NET terms, your variable `claimsIdentity` now holds the same reference as was found in `.Identity`, but they both refer to the same, **single** object, somewhere in memory.

So when you changed that object, well, you changed that object.